# Visual Studio 2008 publishing .svn folders

Tags: visual-studio, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Does anyone know how to prevent VS copying the .svn folders associated with subversion when publishing a web project?

I'm using Tortoise SVN and Ankh svn VS plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I must say I've never had this problem, when you hit publish - do you check the option to only copy the files needed for running the application? (there's a third option which copies everything from the project folder which isn't very useful)

(uncheck hidden on the .svn folder and then check Show all files in VS and they will show up, but as you don't see them to begin with they shouldn't for some weird reason be a part of the project anyway)

Comment: As a note on this, if files that need to be published aren't published , check that they're included in the project, and marked with a build action of "Content" in the file properties.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the .svn folders and hit "Exclude from Project".

Comment: .svn folders are not visible from within VS

Comment: VS should not be copying things that haven't been added to the project.  It might be worth un-setting the invis bit on the .svn directories, adding, then manually excluding them.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the problem but I don't know why it worked.

I simply deleted the .svn folder from the bin folder and it now it ignores all .svn folders.

Weird.

Comment: deleting the .svn folder is only temporary, next time you update you need to do an svn update --force to repair your working copy.

Comment: Not to interfere with version control practices, but having a bin folder version-controlled seems like an issue - it shouldn't be checked in at all to begin with? (and if it wasn't and there was a stray .svn folder in the working copy for some reason - deleting it would fix it)